# How to replace array keys with another array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to replace the second array keys with the first array values if both keys matches.

As an example: Replace A with Code And B with name

How to do this;

```
<?php

        $array = array('A' => 'code', 'B' =>'name');
        $replacement_keys = array
        (
            array("A"=>'sara','B'=>2020),
            array("A"=>'ahmed','B'=>1010)

        );
        foreach($replacement_keys as $key => $value){
                foreach($value as $sk => $sv){
                    foreach($array as $rk => $rv){
                      if($sk == $rk ){
                          $sk = $rv;
                      }
                    }

                }

        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($value);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
```

I want the result to be like this

```
 array(

      [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ahmed
                    [code] => 1020
                )

      [1] => Array
                (
                  [name] => sara
                  [code] => 2020
        )

)
```

Comment: At the second look your expected result has no logic. You want to replace A with `name` and B with `code`, but in your array it's the exact opposite!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array('A' => 'code', 'B' =>'name');
$replacement_keys = array
(
    array("A"=>'sara','B'=>2020),
    array("A"=>'ahmed','B'=>1010)

);

foreach($replacement_keys as &$value)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $name) {
        $value[$name] = $value[$key];
        unset($value[$key]);
    }

}
var_dump($replacement_keys);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = array('A' => 'code', 'B' =>'name');
$replacement_keys = array
(
    array("A"=>'sara','B'=>2020),
    array("A"=>'ahmed','B'=>1010)

);

$newArray = array();
foreach($replacement_keys as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if(isset($array[$key2]))
        {
            $newArray[$key][$array[$key2]] = $value2;
        }
        else
        {
            $newArray[$key][$key2] = $value2;   
        }
    }
}
print_R($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, nice and simple <sub>(I'm going to assume that A should be name and B should be code)</sub>:

(Here I go through each array from `$replacement_keys` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and replace the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) of `$array`. Then I simply get all array values from `$replacement_keys` and finally I [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the replaced array keys with the corresponding array values)

```
$result = array_map("array_combine", 
            array_map(function($v)use($array){
                return str_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), array_keys($v));
            }, $replacement_keys),
            $replacement_keys
        );
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => sara [name] => 2020 ) [1] => Array ( [code] => ahmed [name] => 1010 ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array_fill_keys
```

(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

`array_fill_keys` — Fill an array with values, specifying keys

Description

```
array array_fill_keys ( array $keys , mixed $value )
```

- *Fills an array with the value of the value parameter, using the values of the keys array as keys.*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php